# Create table 6 x 6 with automatic spill from upline

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I am creating a code to company MMN. the idea is a system which has a table 6 x 6 with automatic spill.

For example.

I register 6 new persons.

1. John
2. Peter
3. Mary
4. Lary
5. Anderson
6. Paul

When I register my 7th the system automatic follow the order below me and put into John network. When I register the 8th the system automatic follow the order below me and put into Peter network.

Table 6 x 6
Firt level:  6
Second level: 36

I am trying to creating a test with stored procedure in sqlserver.

I am stuck in the part how I can do automatically put the new person registered to below me when I reach the limit of the table.

Comment: Please show us what you have so far, and we will be better able to help.

Comment: it is matrix 6 x 6 forced. any expert ?

Comment: I have the insert query working. I have a sp to count how many users is registered of upline. Now I need to force the matrix 6 x 6 automatically.

Comment: Did the answer below suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Matrix would be denormalizing your data. It is usually best practice **NOT** to do this, as it makes data manipulation a lot more difficult, among other reasons. How would you prevent the rows from being more than 6? You'd have to add a weird constraint like so:

```
create table #matrix ( ID int identity(1,1),
                        Name1 varchar(64),
                        Name2 varchar(64),
                        Name3 varchar(64),
                        Name4 varchar(64),
                        Name5 varchar(64),
                        Name6 varchar(64),
            CONSTRAINT ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            CONSTRAINT Configuration_SixRows CHECK (ID <= 6))
```

I'm betting you aren't doing this, and thus, you can't "ensure" no more than 6 rows is inserted into your table. If you are doing this, then you'd have to insert data **one row at a time** which goes against everything SQL Server is about. This would be to check if the first column is *full* yet, then move to the second, then the third, etc... it just doesn't make sense.

Instead, I would create a `ParentID` column to relate your names to their respective *network* as you stated. This can be done with a computed column like so:

```
declare @table table (ID int identity(1,1), 
                      Names varchar(64), 
                      ParentID as case 
                                     when ID <= 6 then null 
                                     else replace(ID % 6,0,6) 
                                  end)

insert into @table
values
('John')
,('Peter')
,('Mary')
,('Lary')
,('Anderson')
,('Paul')
,('Seven')
,('Eight')
,('Nine')
,('Ten')
,('Eleven')
,('Twelve')
,('Thirteen')
,('Fourteen')


select * from @table
```

Then, if you wanted to display it in a *matrix* you would use `PIVOT()`, specifically [Dynamic Pivot](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/). There are a lot of examples on Stack Overflow on how to do this. This also accounts for if you want the matrix to be larger than 6 X N... perhaps the network grows so each member has 50 individuals... thus 6 (rows) X 51 (columns)

**IF** it's only going to be 6 columns, or not many more, then you can also use a simple join logic...

```
select
    t.ID
    ,t.Names
    ,t2.Names
    ,t3.Names
from @table t
left join
    @table t2 on t2.ParentID = t.ID and t2.ID = t.ID + 6
left join
    @table t3 on t3.ParentID = t.ID and t3.ID = t.ID + 12
--continue on
where
    t.ParentID is null
```

You can see this in action with **[This OnLine DEMO](http://rextester.com/TBFYR74483)**

[Here is some information on normalization](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/database-normalization-basics)